# How to Add the values of List<string> into the List<PictureBox> after encoding it to Barcode in c#

Tags: c#, printing, bitmap, barcode, picturebox

I have two List one is of string and the other is of PictureBox type. I want to take the values of List of type string and the convert it into the Barcode then save it to the List of type PictureBox.

I am doing it like this right now:

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox> PictureBoxList = new List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox>();
List<string> SerialNumberList = new List<string>();
int SerialNumberStart = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    SerialNumberStart++;
    SerialNumberList.Add("S" + SerialNumberStart);
}

private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int j =0 ; j < SerialNumberList.Count ; j++)
   {
    BarcodeLib.TYPE barcodetype1 = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39;
    BarcodeLib.Barcode bar1 = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
    bar1.IncludeLabel = true;
    PictureBoxList[j].Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1 ,SerialNumberList[j]); // It gives me exception of Index out of range
    PictureBoxList.Add(PictureBoxList[j]);
    printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
    printDocument1.Print();
   }
}

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap myBitmap1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
  pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap1, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap1, 0, 0);
  myBitmap1.Dispose();
}
```

My first question is that How can I convert the string into the PictureBox.
And then converting each item of the PictureBox to the Bitmap and then printing all of the bitmaps now the code only Prints one barcode

Comment: inside `PrintButton_Click` method, you used `j` as looping counter variable, but used `i` all over codes inside the loop instead of `j`. Typo or...?

Comment: Sorry edited my code @har07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you want like this.. right??  see this is the representaion of the this string "S1253551" in 3of9 and plain text and finally as image right??

```
    public Image stringToImage(string inputString)
    { 
        string text = inputString.Trim();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        //Set the font style of output image
        Font font = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
        int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height;

        int height2 = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font2).Height;

        bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(width, height+height2));
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);



        //Specify the background color of the image
        graphics.Clear(Color.Cyan);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;



        //Specify the text, font, Text Color, X position and Y position of the image
        graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
        graphics.DrawString(text, font2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, height);

        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Dispose();

        //if you want to save the image  uncomment the below line.
        //bmp.Save(@"d:\myimage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return bmp;
    }
```

## Remember you must have installed "free 3 of 9" font.

you pass the string "S1253551" and it generate the barcode and add the plain text at bottom and finally return it as image.

Its working code i have tried at my end.  Enjoy. :)

Download the working code from here [Download](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2di1nR2Q3aEtzRDg)

Comment: Can I set this value to the PictureBox or just Have to make an ImageList?

Comment: Its not printing when I click on the Print Button its giving me empty page

Comment: nosheen you have to call this method for particular or for all the string u want. it will return you the image one for one call and then do whatever u want with this image. 

its upto you, you want to display destroy save or whatever u want.

Comment: Yes its showing me the image in the PictureBox but how can I print this on a page? :/ really confused seriously

Comment: i have created the sample for u but thats the window form i mean try give the string and click to generate it.. its list based as u want I will upload in my google doc and will share the link with u..

Comment: find the window form sample 
[Download window form sample](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2di1nR2Q3aEtzRDg)

Answer (score 0):

mean you have string and you have converted it to barcode. finally we have a property in barcode which holds the value of string right?? now you want to display that string as image??

if so then refer the below code -

```
    public Image stringToImage(string inputString)
    {
        string text = inputString.Trim();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        //Set the font style of output image
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
        int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height;

        bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(width, height));
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);



        //Specify the background color of the image
        graphics.Clear(Color.Cyan);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;



        //Specify the text, font, Text Color, X position and Y position of the image
        graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Dispose();

        //if you want to save the image  uncomment the below line.
        //bmp.Save(@"d:\myimage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but actually I have a List of String and with respect to each string I want to create a Barcode and then save it into the List of PictureBox then Pass each element of the PictureBox to the Bitmap. How can I pass the width and Height of each element into the Bitmap constructor?

Comment: i am sorry but i dont know what u mean by "create barcode.....".  I can tell you how to create list of image or imagebox having the same image from the list of string - 

list of string -> list of image 
list of string -> List of picture box

Comment: Yes I want this what you are saying

Comment: you mean you want list of image from the list of string right?? then you can use the above code also.. call the above function for each string in list or change the function itself which accepts the list of string and return the list of image.

Comment: But I want the images in the format of Barcode for this I am using the Encode method

Comment: let me check the barcode. I have never tried it.. if I got it i will post it here.

Comment: so you are using the barcode lib? sorry but i dont have, and i can not try it ..
but the above code works perfectly incase if you want to show the string as image. mean want to convert string as image.

remember the captcha?? it also has string in format of image. I am aware with barcode.

Comment: No its not working fine It gives me exception and you can check the main problem which I am facing from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228198/how-to-print-the-barcode-format-in-c-sharp

Comment: okay so i have seen your another post. whats the type of barcode? is it an image?? if yes then u need to merge string with an image and want result as image. right?

Comment: I am just using Font Free 3 of 9 and applying it to the Gridview column.

Comment: yes now i got it.. right.. but the only thing i want to know this barcode represent the same string??

I mean S11008760  and corresponding barcode is the representation of the "S11008760" this string??  I am also done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, *if* `bar1.Encode` actually has return type of `Image`, this lines in `PrintButton_Click` method :

```
PictureBoxList[j].Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1 ,SerialNumberList[j]); // It gives me exception of Index out of range
PictureBoxList.Add(PictureBoxList[j]);
```

should be like this :

```
var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1 ,SerialNumberList[j]); 
PictureBoxList.Add(pictureBox);
```

**UPDATE :**

To make it clear, my answer above meant `PrintButton_Click` should be as follow :

```
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for(int j =0 ; j < SerialNumberList.Count ; j++)
   {
        BarcodeLib.TYPE barcodetype1 = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39;
        BarcodeLib.Barcode bar1 = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
        bar1.IncludeLabel = true;
        var pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Image = bar1.Encode(barcodetype1 ,SerialNumberList[j]);
        PictureBoxList.Add(pictureBox);
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        printDocument1.Print();
   }
}
```

Comment: The first one will give the Index out of range exception as I have tried it as well , And the second one will work fine if I know the number of PictureBoxes but in my case I do not know how many PictureBox will I need so want to make it dynamic

Comment: I meant, you need to replace part of your code (that shown in the first code block of my answer) with the second code block. No need to know the number of PictureBoxes..

Comment: I have used your code but now I have to print this to a page and for that I have to convert this to a bitmap and pass the Width and Height of each of the PictureBox.